# Scalability of JSON

Tags: javascript, json

1. Is reading/parsing a JSON object (such as through a `<script>` DOM node, e.g. JSONP) a synchronous blocking operation for (most) browsers?
2. At what point is a JSON object too large to where client-side operations on the object would be prohibitive (e.g. locking up browser, script running too slow, etc.)?

Comment: 1) no : you're always calling (ajax way) json loading asynchronously. 2) just test. And use small loading as soon as it's too long.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, parsing a JSON string is a blocking operation. (Note that if you're consuming JSONP from a web service then you're not explicitly having to parse a string into JS).

You'd have to have a *really* large JSON string for this to be a problem with modern browsers. If you find that an operation does lock up the browser, you could avoid this by a web worker, which allows the blocking operation to be done in a separate thread.

Comment: also, its easy to check a worst case time - `var t = Date.now(); JSON.parse( test_10MB_json ); var delta = Date.now() - t` - and you have your estimate. (i bet IE7 would not like it, but modern browsers should do just fine)

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, parsing JSON is blocking. The sign of a non-blocking operation is passing a callback like so:

```
$.get('/stuff/1', function (data) {
    // do stuff with `data`
});
```

whereas a block operation is written normally like this

```
var stuff = JSON.parse(theData);
```

If `JSON.parse` were non-blocking it would look like this:

```
JSON.parse(theData, function (stuff) {
    // process `stuff`
});
```

Parsing JSON is a very fast operation so it doesn't need to be non-blocking.

2) Really big. Parsing JSON, especially in browsers with a native `JSON.parse` method (nearly all of them) is quite speedy. JSON is a simple format and therefore is quick to parse.